# SQL Match Special Characters Regexp

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm looking for an SQL statement that will return only rows of my table whose `Name` field contains special characters (excluding underscores).

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE Name REGEXP '^[!#$%&()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~]+$'
```

But no dice, this returns an empty result set (despite there being rows I specifically added with Name fields containing `%, $, and #` characters).

Comment: See examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604727/oracle-sql-regexp-like-contains-characters-other-than-a-z-or-a-z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem seems to be is the `^` and `$` signs (Mike C summarized it quicker than I did why...)

But I see escaping problems too: all special characters that mean something in regexp should be <del>escaped</del> specially placed in the `[]`, so `[`, `]`, `^`, `-`

Here is a question about [how to escape special characters inside character groups in MySQL regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141211/list-of-metacharacters-for-mysql-regexp-square-brackets).

Conclusion detailed in the [regex documentation](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=7&topic=regex):

> A bracket expression is a list of characters enclosed in '[]'.  It normally  matches  any single character from the list (but see below).
>
> - If the list begins with '^', it matches  any  single  character  (but  see
>        below)  not  from  the rest of the list.
> - If two characters in the list are separated by '-', this is shorthand for the full range  of  characters  between  those  two  (inclusive)  in the collating sequence, e.g.
>        '[0-9]' in ASCII matches any decimal digit.
> - It is illegal(!)  for  two ranges  to share an endpoint, e.g. 'a-c-e'.  Ranges are very collating sequence-dependent, and portable programs should avoid relying on them.
> - To include a literal ']' in the list, make it the first character (following a possible '^').
> - To include a literal '-', make it the first orlast  character,  or  the second endpoint of a range.
> - To use a literal '-' as the first endpoint of a range, enclose it in '[.'  and  '.]'  to make  it  a collating element (see below).
>
> With the exception of these and some combinations using '[' (see next paragraphs), **all  other  special  characters, including '\', lose their special significance within
>   a bracket expression**.

**EDIT**
[Here is an SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfc4c/3) about some interesting regexes regarding the `]` character

**DDL:**
    create table txt (
      txt varchar(200)
      );

```
insert into txt values ('ab[]cde');
insert into txt values ('ab[cde');
insert into txt values ('ab]cde');
insert into txt values ('ab[]]]]cde');
insert into txt values ('ab[[[[]cde');
insert into txt values ('ab\\]]]]cde');
insert into txt values ('ab[wut?wut?]cde');
```

**Queries:**

Naive approach to match a group of `[` and `]` chars. Syntactically OK, but the group is the single `[` char, and it matches multiple `]` chars afterwards.

```
SELECT * FROM txt WHERE txt 
REGEXP 'ab[[]]+cde';
```

Escaped -> same ???

```
SELECT * FROM txt WHERE txt 
REGEXP 'ab[[\]]+cde';
```

Double escape -> doesn't work, group is now a `[` and a `\`

```
SELECT * FROM txt WHERE txt 
REGEXP 'ab[[\\]]+cde';
```

Swapping the closing bracket with the opening one inside the group. This is the weirdest regex I ever wrote - to this point...

```
SELECT * FROM txt WHERE txt 
REGEXP 'ab[][]+cde';
```

I will get killed by such a (totally valid!) regex in a weird nightmare, I think:

```
SELECT * FROM txt WHERE txt 
REGEXP 'ab[]wut?[]+cde';
```

Comment: Thanks ppeterka, and +1 for raising the issue of the required escapes

Comment: @MikeC I was partially wrong about it, tried to write a SQL fiddle, and found interesting results in this topic, which I added to my answer... Very strange, I was convinced they can be reasonably escaped, but I couldn't get `]` to behave... Here is the fiddle for it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfc4c/3

Answer (score 3):

This regex should match names that ONLY contain special characters. You specify the carat (^) which signifies the start of the string, your character class with your list of special characters, the plus sign (+) to indicate one or more, and then the dollar to signify the end of the string. You need to account for non-special character in the string. You could try something like this:

```
WHERE Name REGEXP '^.*?[!#$%&()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~]+.*?$'
```

I added the .*? at the beginning and end to allow for non-special characters before and after the special character. BTW, you probably don't need the (+) any more, since one special would be enough for a match.