# replacing square brackets of a string with oracle REGEXP_REPLACE function

Tags: regex, oracle

I want to replace square brackets in string with REGEXP_REPLACE function. Even I escape these chracters it's not replacing

```
select regexp_replace('VMI[[DATA]]INFO', '[\[\]]', '_') from dual;
```

result

```
VMI[[DATA]]INFO
```

How can we do this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select regexp_replace('VMI[[DATA]]INFO', '\[|\]', '_') from dual;
```

But I don't think that regular expressions are needed here, you can also use TRANSLATE

```
select translate('VMI[[DATA]]INFO', '[]', '__') from dual;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/18788)

Comment: As a developer have common tendency to use regular expression for replacing and have no idea about translate() function of oracle. Now I am using translate() as suggested by you. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Inside character classes, you don't need escapes. Special rules apply for -, ] and ^, for obvious reasons (see e.g. [List of metacharacters for MySQL square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141211/list-of-metacharacters-for-mysql-regexp-square-brackets) )

So in your case, you can use

```
select regexp_replace('VMI[[DATA]]INFO', '[][]', '_') from dual;
```

but I agree with @A.B.Cade - regular expresssions are overkill for this.

Comment: The documentation link given is for MySQL but the question is for Oracle - a better link would be [Oracle 12c Database SQL Language Reference - Multilingual Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix001.htm#SQLRF55540).

Answer (score 0):

To explain what is happening. Your regular expression `[\[\]]` is matching:

- A bracket expression `[\[\]` which matches either a `\`  character or a `[` character or a `\`  character (since `\`  is not an escape character in Oracle's regular expression syntax but is treated as a character literal).
- Followed by a `]` character.

So your regular expression would match a sub-string that was either `\]` or `[]`.

---

From the [Oracle 12c Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix001.htm#SQLRF55540):

> Bracket expression for specifying a matching list that should match any one of the expressions represented in the list. A non-matching list expression begins with a circumflex (`^`) and specifies a list that matches any character except for the expressions represented in the list.
>
> To specify a right bracket (`]`) in the bracket expression, place it first in the list (after the initial circumflex (`^`), if any).
>
> To specify a hyphen in the bracket expression, place it first in the list (after the initial circumflex (`^`), if any), last in the list, or as an ending range point in a range expression.

So, if you want to match a closing square bracket in a bracket expression then it needs to be the first character in the list and your regular expression should be `[][]`. The first `[` starts the bracket expression; the `]` second character is to match a closing square bracket character; the `[` third character matches an opening square bracket character; and the final `]` terminates the bracket expression.

Which would give the solution as:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         'VMI[[DATA]]INFO',
         '[][]',
         '_'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```