# why cannot match char of ']' with regexp_like in oracle?

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-like

When I input these SQLs, they return result `1`:

**sql 1**:

`select 1 from dual where regexp_like('R[23','^[[0-9a_zA-Z]+$');`

returns `1`

**sql 2**:

`select 1 from dual where regexp_like('[]','^\\[\\]$');`

returns `1`

---

But when I input this SQL, it cannot return result with `1`

**sql 3**:

`select 1 from dual where regexp_like('R23]','^[0-9a_zA-Z\\]]+$');`

returns `null`

Comment: **SQL 2** does not output `1`. You want `select 1 from dual where regexp_like('[]','^\[]$');` with only a single `\ ` escape character to prevent the bracket expression from starting. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=46b1c0f9ce71e5111aa801c750571d44).

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19420806/3832970) is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put the closing square bracket first in the regular expression and do not escape it:

```sql
SELECT 1
FROM   dual
WHERE  regexp_like( 'R23]', '^[]0-9a-zA-Z]+$');
```

You also want `a-z` rather than `a_z`.

From the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix001.htm#SQLRF55540):

> Bracket expression for specifying a matching list that should match any one of the expressions represented in the list. A non-matching list expression begins with a circumflex (`^`) and specifies a list that matches any character except for the expressions represented in the list.
>
> To specify a right bracket (`]`) in the bracket expression, place it first in the list (after the initial circumflex (`^`), if any).
>
> To specify a hyphen in the bracket expression, place it first in the list (after the initial circumflex (`^`), if any), last in the list, or as an ending range point in a range expression.

Your expression (after correcting `_` to `-`):

```sql
SELECT  1
FROM    DUAL
WHERE   regexp_like('R23]','^[0-9a-zA-Z\\]]+$');
```

Is matching to see if there is a character which matches one of the characters `0123456789abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\\` at the start of the string (there is no escape character in the regular expression so `\` is treated as part of the character group to match) and then is followed by one-or-more `]` characters and then the end of the string.

So:

```sql
SELECT  1
FROM    DUAL
WHERE   regexp_like('\]]]]]]]]]]','^[0-9a-zA-Z\\]]+$');
```

Outputs `1`

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9d7d467168d042d7c25d20f3814743da)