# An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash

Tags: regex, string, delimiter

I want to match literal `/` character in regexp, so I use `[/]`. Using [this example](https://regex101.com/r/IbleYi/1) results in

> / An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash ()

Am I wrong or is the website wrong? As far as I know, all characters inside square brackets `[]` must be present as literal without escape character.

Please, clarify to me.

EDIT:
I use MySQL. How is `/` should be presented if I want to meet literal `/`? Is using `[/]` the right thing? Or `[\/]`?

Comment: What flavor/language? And no, brackets don't change the meaning of / since / is not part of the expression. It's an external delimiter.

Comment: If `/` is your default regex delimiter, then you need to escape it like `\/` doesn't matter whether it's inside charset or not. But if you change it like you can do in PHP, then you don't even need to escape it outside character class.

Comment: I am using MySQL. Plz note that I am talking about / inside square brackets as I want to match / literally.

Comment: But I use that site to test as it is difficult to test in large data base.

Comment: On regex101 you can change the delimiter (in this case the forward slash). In the input field where you enter the regex there are 3 vertical dots on the left. You can click it and change it to something else than the forward slash.

Comment: @user9371654: In MYSQL db, you don't need to escape `/` and can write `/` as it is. Can you share what MYSQL db version you are using and what is your query that is leading you to this error?

Comment: @Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi I use MySQL workbench 8.0. I do not get any error in MySQL whether I use [/] or [\/]. I tested my regex in regex101 and foud that it requires [\/] and does not accept [/]. So I am worried that writing [\/] in MySQL will lead to something unintended, e.g. matching \ as well. So my understanding is that in MySQL I can use [/] and no need to escape. The issue of requiring escape is special to regex101 website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what delimiter the used language used. It is the character `/` in many languages, so if you use a literal slash you need to escape it (like `[\/]`), or use different delimiter if possible in the language.

Answer (score 1):

The link you have provided it has a pattern error in it. If you wish to pass a forward slash you need a backslash before it in the char list. You might want to use `[\/]` in this site for testing and then remove it when you want to use in MySQL.

[image]

### Correction

[image]

#### Metachars in MySQL

- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141211/list-of-metacharacters-for-mysql-regexp-square-brackets) might help you about metachars in MySQL.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1087208/6553328) also explains metachars in mysql.
- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-do-i-escape-special-characters-in-mysql/881208) explains how to escape meta chars in MySQL.

Comment: I understand. But I am surprised why this happened in that wesite? as I know that if I want to meet literal characters I put it as-is in the square brackets. I am confused what should I do in MySQL? should I put [/] literally or escape it [\/] like the website editor?