# Regular expression does not match input string

Tags: regex

I'm pretty new to regexp and I don't get why this expression is not matching the string

Regular expression:
`^$0$.*|$5$(rounds=\d+$)?[a-zA-Z0-9./]{1,16}$[a-zA-Z0-9./]{43}$`

String:
`$5$VcklQoY36plyldTg$cDc5UqmzE.NDnd/HbGXYzntHG9h4xycG2SSUSPH.Ww6`

I see that $5$ in the target string, (rounds=\d+$) is optional. It matches the next 1-16 characters with the character set [a-zA-Z0-9./] and the next 43 characters with the character set [a-zA-Z0-9./]. How does the string not match the expression here?

I'm using the regcomp() and the regexec() functions from the linux regex library.

Comment: You should also provide the code you use to run the regex.

Comment: Added it to the question now.

Comment: Are you escaping your backslashes? Both C and your regex engine will have their own separate escapes, so `\d` should appear in C source as `\\d`, for example.

Comment: FWIW, Regex101.com also tells me your regex is invalid because your two `/` characters need to be escaped as well (assuming you're using a PCRE-style regex engine)

Comment: All but the last `$` should be `\$` (and thus `\\$` in a string literal)

Comment: Assuming the string escaping is taken care of you'll still need to escape those `$` symbols so you can match literal $. `^\$0\$.*|\$5\$(rounds=\d+\$)?[a-zA-Z0-9./]{1,16}\$[a-zA-Z0-9./]{43}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` symbol represents the end of a string in regex. If you want to match literal `$` character it should be escaped.

Fixed regex: `^\$0\$.*|\$5\$(rounds=\d+\$)?[a-zA-Z0-9./]{1,16}\$[a-zA-Z0-9./]{43}$`

[Interactive example](https://regexr.com/7aldd).

Comment: @ikegami you are right, it depends on what delimiter the used language used.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56101840/an-unescaped-delimiter-must-be-escaped-with-a-backslash

Answer (score 0):

`$` has a special meaning in regex patterns. You need to escape it when you want to match a `$` literally.

Also, you probably also meant to have a `^` in the right half of the alternation.

```
^\$0\$.*|^\$5\$(rounds=\d+\$)?[a-zA-Z0-9./]{1,16}\$[a-zA-Z0-9./]{43}$
```

or

```
^\$(0\$.*|5\$(rounds=\d+\$)?[a-zA-Z0-9./]{1,16}\$[a-zA-Z0-9./]{43})$
```

You didn't show your code, so you could also have made a mistake creating a C string literal that produces the above string. Keep in mind that `\` is special in C string literals, so you need to escape it. (Same goes for `"`, but you're not using it.)

```c
"^\\$(0\\$.*|5\\$(rounds=\\d+\\$)?[a-zA-Z0-9./]{1,16}\\$[a-zA-Z0-9./]{43})$"
```

This is what should appear in your code.